# How can i get the response url using Retrofit2 in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, spotify

Some background, I'm trying to do `Spotify's` [authorization code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow). And for now I'm stuck at requesting user authorization. The problem is that the response body is in the url as query parameters appended to the callback redirect uri that I provided to Spotify. As the application I'm doing is an `Android Kotlin` application(the relevant part is that it's Kotlin).

Therefore I need to somehow get the query parameters and didn't find any support in `Retrofit2`. So I focused my attention on getting the url instead and parse the url for the query parameters, but I don't know how to do that either. All the searching on `Stackoverflow` got me to how to get the request url, but that it isn't of any use to me, I want the response url. So the question is how do I actually get the response url in `Kotlin` using `Retrofit2`? Or if I can somehow get query parameters directly that'll be better.

Preferably the answer won't contain `Call<>` and `.enqueue()` since in Kotlin you can't use both suspend functions and `Call<>` and doing suspend is preferable. Also as a personal preference I'm doing it using `Retrofit2` instead of using the `Spotify SDK` and I think it should be possible this way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the documentation closer.
`okhttp3.Response` which you can get from `Retrofit2` networking have property `request`.
`OkHttp3` explains about this property like below.

> The wire-level request that initiated this HTTP response. This is not necessarily the same request issued by the application:
> It may be transformed by the HTTP client. For example, the client may copy headers like Content-Length from the request body.
> It may be the request generated in response to an HTTP redirect or authentication challenge. In this case the request URL may be different than the initial request URL.

Which means you can get response query from `okhttp3.Response` like this way.

```
 response.request.url.query
```

If you have `retrofit2.response` you can grab `okhttp3.Response` by using `raw()` method.

Comment: Won't this give me the query params of the request that I sent? I know what I sent, I needed the query params for the response. Anyway I used the Spotify SDK in the end, it seems downright impossible do to this with Retrofit.

Comment: @RetroGhost  `response.request.url` could be responseURL what server return to the client.